# ESB Service Statistics Monitoring using wso2BAM, toolbox have no data

Tags: wso2, wso2-cep, wso2-bam, wso2-esb

I am using wso2BAM 2.4.1 with wso2ESB 4.6, I first edited the

> /repository/conf/etc/bam.xml

file and enabled the ServiceDataPublishing feature. Then I setup the BAM `Service Data Pblishing` feature from the [repository](http://dist.wso2.org/p2/carbon/releases/4.1.0) on the ESB. After I configured the `Service Data Pblishing` and my job on the esb got done.

I used the Cassandra Explorer and saw the logs are saving to the Cassandra under the stream name I set in the ESB `Service Data Pblishing` configurations.

Everything went well till I installed the `Service_Statistics_Monitoring` toolbox to view data about services and real-time request and response counts.

Since the stream name in the `Service_Statistics_Monitoring` and `Service data Publishing` are the same (both are `bam_service_data_publisher`) I got error in the esb logs for sending data to BAM. I change the stream name in the ESB and the data publishing error gone but still I can not see any data be shown on the dashboard with the `Service_Statistics_Monitoring` toolbox and it has errors of no data found like the picture below. I have to mention that data is still published to BAM and saved in a table with the new stream name.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I resolved the problem! the fact is you should be careful about the **version** of your stream in ESB and BAM! The stream name of the `Service_Statistics_Monitoring Toolbox` and bam streams in ESB, AS and other wso2 products should be the same if you want to see the results in the toolbox dashboard, but you should change the version of the streams, the `Service_Statistics_Monitoring Toolbox` occupies the 1.0.0 version so you have to change the version of other bam streams that you want to monitor using the toolbox.

Comment: Hi Reza Ameri. Currently I have got the same problem, and I also did exactly as your suggestion. I change the stream name - version 1.0.0 and the data has already appeared in BAM Event-KS. I also changed the hive script (cf.name) to the new stream name. But I'm unable to view the service status neither on dashboard nor report document. It took me days with headache, please help me. I'm using WSO2 ESB 4.8.1 and BAM 2.5.0

Comment: @ThienDinh why did you change the hive script if you already could see the reports and data?

Comment: Hi Reza, I change both stream name and cf.name. But after long time and got nothing, I reset the configuration. Step by step, all I could see in the dashboard is : host, service, operator name, but the request/response/fault  is always counted as 0. It's really confused :(

Comment: And I found  that ESB is unable to transfer payload_request_count or payload_request_response :( . Bam cann't get that data.

Comment: I really have to see it, I have no idea by this time :( sorry.